# Launch Telegram Desktop using python in Ubuntu

Tags: python, linux

First of all, I am a beginner in the Linux environment

I have used the command below in python to open the Telegram Desktop in the Windows 10 environment and it works correctly:

```
subprocess.Popen('C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Telegram Desktop\\Telegram.exe')
```

But now I want to do the same thing in python but in the **Ubuntu** environment. I have used the command below to do it but it does not work:

```
subprocess.Popen('\\home\\username\\snap\\telegram-desktop\\2551\\.local\\share\\TelegramDesktop')
```

Error = "No such a file or directory"

Maybe I have a problem with the installation path for the telegram. Consider that I found the path using <**locate**> command in terminal

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? What is the problem exactly? Did it throw any error?

Comment: It says: Errno 2 No such file or directory

Comment: Have you checked that the file actually exists? Can you run it without a Python program?

Comment: I can run it using the shortcut in the "Show applications" part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of historical reasons, Windows uses the backslash symbol (`\`) as the path separator, while Linux/UNIX systems use the forward-slash (`/`).

When a path begins with `/`, it is interpreted as an absolute path, otherwise, it is treated as a relative one (if it contains at least one forward-slash) or as a command which can be found by the `PATH` environment variable.

When you write

```py
subprocess.Popen('\\home\\username\\snap\\telegram-desktop\\2551\\.local\\share\\TelegramDesktop')
```

Python tries to find a file in the `PATH` with has this big 70-characters long name. If you want to specify an absolute file path instead, you should do

```py
subprocess.Popen('/home/username/snap/telegram-desktop/2551/.local/share/TelegramDesktop')
```

If this still throws the `FileNotFound` exception, it's most likely that you have just specified a wrong file path. If you're having the Permission Denied error, you might not have the executing permission for this file (learn more by searching for "Linux execute permission")

Answer (score 1):

Unix uses `/` as a path separator. You have `\\` instead which makes this look like one long file name, not a path.

Comment: Thank you for your responce
I changed them now another error occurred which says : Permission denied errno 13
what should I do?

Comment: @Soheilyns I suggest you google the error to learn more about it.